# What is the best user interface you have ever used/seen in real-world or real-world objects?

Tags: physical

Exclude all web/mobile/application/computer software interfaces.

Comment: I find that soccer balls, mountains, the sea, cats and many women have great interfaces. Pianos - not so much.

Comment: @Vitaly Mijiritsky Priceless.

Comment: "I like an escalator because an escalator can never break, it can only become stairs. There would never be an escalator temporarily out of order sign, only an 'Escalator temporarily stairs. Sorry for the convenience.'" - Mitch Hedberg

Comment: I like this question, but it doesn't fit the Stack Exchange model. See the [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information on what is considered a good question.

Comment: Enter the question police.  Exit good conversations.

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney - [DC Escalator collapses](http://voices.washingtonpost.com/dr-gridlock/2011/02/metro_escalator_steps_collapse.html), leaving dangerous chasm...

Comment: @Glen - as has been stated *many* times before - this is not a discussion site. It is a Q&A site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to name these things because, as with all well-designed items, we don't think of them as well-designed, because they so naturally fit into our lives. Think about toothbrushes, doorknobs, drawers, light switches (though they could be better, yes). They all have user interfaces (because they can be interacted with by a user) and they all are nearly perfect.

Also, look at musical instruments. They evolved for hundreds of years and have achieved a high level of perfection.

Comment: I would add to that list hand tools like an axe, hammer, or knife, things that have been around for hundreds or even thousands of years and have been perfected over time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say either:

- An ATM machine - although they are a bit more complex nowadays, but back when they only offered withdrawal of cash (not phone topups, deposits etc that they offer now).
- Pedestrian traffic crossing signals - single button interface with clear feedback to the user as to what to do.

It could be argued that neither of these require training to use and while not 100% instinctive are pretty darn close.

Comment: What's an automated teller machine machine? A machine that creates ATM's?

Comment: Ok, I guess I deserved that. ;-)

Comment: @Rahulmax — 
Not even “ATMs”. “ATM”.

Answer (score 1):

I like wall-mounted manual PET bottle compactors. The sound of plastic crounching with just a minimal force application while knowing that you did something good for the environment is really satisfactory.